# bigquery standard sql get dayofweek

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In Bigquery standard sql how to extract day of a week (number)? 
We can do this in Legacy sql using DAYOFWEEK function but couldn't find any equivalent function in the standard sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE())
```

see more for [`EXTRACT(part FROM date_expression)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract)

Comment: Is there a way to set Monday as the first day instead of the default Sunday?

Comment: @AlphaCR
you can use WEEK(<WEEKDAY>) for this.

Bigquery documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract